# Template.instance() and context messed with with Blaze block helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm using a simple template block helper that displays the a loading animation, hiding whatever is within it. This is very helpful for submitting forms and preventing the button from being pressed twice.

```
<template name="waiting">
  {{#if isLoading}}
      {{> loader}}
  {{else}}
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

I decided to put it in a block helper because I've never tried it before and I wanted to keep my code DRY -- I'm using this pattern in several places.

I'm running into issues using this block helper to access the `Template.instance()` not of the block helper but of the template it is within. I'm also running into problems with the template context. Here are the details of my problem:

I'm setting up a confirm-delete button like so:

```
  {{#waiting isLoading=loadingDelete}}
    {{#if confirmDelete}}
      <button class="confirm">Are you sure?</button>
    {{else}}
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    {{/if}}
  {{/waiting}}
```

I'm also putting the `loadingDelete` and `confirmDelete` reactive variables in the template instance so I don't contaminate the `Session`:

```
Template.editRecord.created = ->
  @loadingDelete = new ReactiveVar(false)
  @confirmDelete = new ReactiveVar(false)

Template.editRecord.helpers
  loadingDelete: () -> Template.instance().loadingDelete.get()
  confirmDelete: () -> Template.instance().confirmDelete.get()
```

Then I create some events like this:

'click .delete': (e,t) ->
    t.confirm.set(true)

'click .confirm': (e,t) ->
    t.loadingDelete.set(true)
    _id = @_id
    Meteor.call 'deleteRecord', _id, (err) ->
      t.loadingDelete.set(false)
      if err
        console.log err
      else
        Router.go "home"

The problem with this implementation is that the `Template.instance()` refers to the waiting template in the `confirmDelete` helper here:

```
confirmDelete: () -> Template.instance().confirmDelete.get()
```

The second problem is that the data context in the event refers to the context of the waiting template and thus I need to use `_id = Template.parentData()_id` instead of `_id = @_id`. But I am not able to access the editRecord template instance or any of its variables from here which is frustrating.

I changed the template to this which fixes first problem.

```
  {{#if confirmDelete}}
    <button class="confirm">Are you sure?</button>
  {{else}}
    {{#waiting isLoading=loadingDelete}}
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    {{/waiting}}
  {{/if}}
```

But this is ugly and not what I was intending. I was hoping just to replace my `#if` block with this block helper but I've ended up writing much more code while trying to be DRY with my templates. This just doesn't seem right.

I noticed that `#if` blocks don't cause these context and Template instance problems. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the Meteor team has recognized this error and are working to fix it. See this [PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3546).